# How to order search results according to PageRank scores

Tags: python, django

I am working on a search engine that produces results with PageRank scores assigned to each link. I want the results to be ordered (sorted)  according to the PageRank score (highest scored links come at the top).

I am not an expert in python, but I used the following code with Django. I put part of the code I used here, please have a look:

https://trinket.io/python/1d3490b96e

How do I order the resulting links accoridng to their given PageRank Score? The scores are stored in a text file, and each link has its own score given during the crawling.

Thanks

Comment: Are you storing this in a database? what kind of data structure do you have?

Comment: consider posting your code

Comment: Hi, thanks guys... The crawling stores the scores and urls to text files... I tried to post the code but it gets trimmed here.. I share a link with the code in my post. Please have a look.